# Article "the" in context

Tags: articles

Tell me please which sentence is correct.

> **1)** I will vote for those with **the** characteristics that I like.
>   **2)** I will vote for those with characteristics that I like.

I am confused whether I need to use "the" or not. However, I favour the first one.

Comment: I can see why you're confused; it doesn't really matter. This is one of those cases where the article is purely optional. They both read fine to my native ear, with virtually no difference in meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct with a very slight difference in meaning.

"The characteristics that I like" implies all of the characteristics that I like.

"Characteristics that I like" implies some of the characteristics that I like.